# How to pass MonoDevelop build configuration to Makefile?

Tags: makefile, monodevelop, buildconfiguration

MonoDevelop supports Makefile integration.
But how do I know current build configuration (Debug/Release) from inside of Makefile?

Comment: The usual way is to set a variable in the same command that invokes Make (e.g. `make myApp BUILD=Release`) and use the variable in the makefile. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Unfortunately MonoDevelop doesn't let you specify different commands for Debug and Release configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't do that. Um, okay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you need to go to your project, right click OPTIONS under BUILD choose CUSTOM COMMANDS and then add a Build command "make"

You can do the same for a "make clean"